# Use a for loop to create several bubble plots with different legend scales in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, plot, legend

I have been trying to make several bubble plots showing the frequency of observations (as a percentage) of several individuals in different sites. Some individuals were found in the same site, but not all. Also the number of locations within each site may vary among individuals. My main problem is that I have more than 3 individuals and more than 3 sites, so I have been trying to come up with a good/fast way of creating this type of bubble plots/legends. I am also having problems with the legend as I need to have a function that will place the legend in the same location when creating a new plot. In the legend I want to show different bubble sizes for each frequency (if possible indicating the value next to the bubble).

Here is an example of my script. Any suggestions or ideas on how to do this will be extremely helpful.

> ```
> # require libraries
> library(maptools)
> library(sp)
>
> data<-read.table(text="ind  lat   long    site    freq    perc
>              A  -18.62303   147.29207   A   449 9.148329258
>              A  -18.6195    147.29492   A   725 14.77180114
>              A  -18.62512   147.3018    A   3589    73.12550937
>              A  -18.62953   147.29422   A   145 2.954360228
>              B  -18.75383   147.25405   B   2   0.364963504
>              B  -18.73393   147.28162   B   1   0.182481752
>              B  -18.62303   147.29207   A   3   0.547445255
>              B  -18.6195    147.29492   A   78  14.23357664
>              B  -18.62512   147.3018    A   451 82.29927007
>              B  -18.62953   147.29422   A   13  2.372262774
>              C  -18.51862   147.39717   C   179 0.863857922
>              C  -18.53281   147.39052   C   20505   98.95757927
>              C  -18.52847   147.40167   C   37  0.178562811",header=TRUE)
>
> # Split data frame for each tag
> ind<-data$ind
> M<-split(data,ind)
> l<-length(M)
>
> ### Detection Plots ###
>
> pdf("Plots.pdf",width=11,height=8,paper="a4r")
> par(mfrow=c(1,1))
>
> for(j in 1:l){
>
>    # locations
>
>    new.data<-M[[j]]
>    site<-as.character(unique(new.data$site))
>
>    fname<-paste(new.data$ind[1],sep="")
>    loc<-new.data[,c("long","lat")]
>    names(loc)<-c("X", "Y")
>    coord<-SpatialPoints(loc)
>    coord1<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(coord,new.data)
>
>    # draw some circles with specify radius size
>
>    x<-new.data$long
>    y<-new.data$lat
>    freq<-new.data$perc
>    rad<-freq
>    rad1<-round(rad,1)
>
>    title<-paste("Ind","-",fname," / ","Site","-",new.data$site[1],sep="")  
>
>    # create bubble plot  
>    symbols(x,y,circles=rad1,inches=0.4,fg="black",bg="red",xlab="",ylab="")
>    points(x,y,pch=1,col="black",cex=0.4)
>
>    par(new=T)
>
>    # map scale  
>    maps::map.scale(grconvertX(0.4,"npc"),grconvertY(0.1, "npc"),
>      ratio=FALSE,relwidth=0.2,cex=0.6)
>
>    # specifying coordinates for legend  
>    legX<-grconvertX(0.8,"npc")
>    legY1<-grconvertY(0.9,"npc")
>    legY2<-legY1-0.001
>    legY3<-legY2-0.0006
>    legY4<-legY3-0.0003
>
>    # creating the legend
>    leg<-data.frame(X=c(legX,legX,legX,legX),Y=c(legY1,legY2,legY3,legY4),
>      rad=c(1000,500,100,25))
>    symbols(leg$X,leg$Y,circles=leg$rad,inches=0.3,add=TRUE,fg="black",bg="white")
>
>    mtext(title,3,line=1,cex=1.2)
>    mtext("Latitude",2,line=3,padj=1,cex=1)
>    mtext("Longitude",1,line=2.5,padj=0,cex=1)
>
>    box()
>
>
> }
>
> dev.off()
> ```

The first plot is actually Ok, and will only need to have the values of the frequency/perc next to the lengend bubble. However, it does not really work with the others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hardcoding the legend position - make it relative...

```
legX<-grconvertX(0.8,"npc")
legY1<-grconvertY(0.9,"npc")

# Get the size of the plotting area (measured on the y axis)
ysize <- par()$usr[4]-par()$usr[3]

# Use that to calculate the new positions
legY2<-legY1 - (0.1* ysize)
legY3<-legY1 - (0.2* ysize)
legY4<-legY1 - (0.3* ysize)
```

This will put the bubbles on the same place on all the plots (in steps of 10% of the plotting area).

Comment: What would be a good way to represent the size of the bubbles (in the plot and legend) as percentages with specific categories (<25%, 25-50%, 50-75% and >75%)? Right now my data is summarize so that each row has the value of %observations, but I also have the raw data with all the observations (freq) per day. Is there a good way to calculate these kind of intervals on a plot for multiple individuals?